# How to pass parameter when loadNib with method [NSBundle loadNibNamed:xibName owner:[NSApplication sharedApplication]]?

Tags: objective-c, xib

When I use `loadNibNamed` method to load a `xib` file, how to pass some parameter?

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:xibName owner:[NSApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Comment: Passing parameters to what?  Typically the object class identified as File's Owner in the XIB contains outlets that allow you to set properties based on other objects that are also in the XIB.  Any settings that are not handled by direct connections can be coded manually in the `awakeFromNib` method (or other methods that are invoked after loading is complete, e.g. `windowDidLoad` for window controllers).  So: let the XIB instantiate your class and then use `awakeFromNib` to customize the instance.

Comment: Passing parameters to awakeFromNib method  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to pass parameters when instantiating your class, add a wrapper to the 
`loadNibNamed:owner:` method and pass your parameters to this wrapper.

Here is the code snippet for this:

> ```
> (ClassName *) GetInstanceWithParameter1:(ParameterType *)param1 
>                             andParameter2:(ParameterType *)param2 {
>      ClassName *instance = [[ClassName alloc] initWithNibNamed:nibName               
>                                                         bundle:nibBundle];
>      instance -> P1 = param1;
>      instance -> P2 = param2;
>      return instance;
> }
> ```

Here P1 and P2 are your class level variable corresponding to param1 and param2. Now you can use them anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of something I did which worked for me.

Say you have a Xib (Nib) file (MyNibView.xib) which is a UIView.

That UIView has a Class linked to it, called NibView, which has a header and a main file; NibView.h and NibView.h.

> If you don't know how to link a class to a Nib:
>
> Click on your Nib > go to Identity Inspector > enter your Class under
>   Custom Class > Class.

1) In NibView.h make sure you have the object (that you want to pass through) instantiated. For this example I will use a NSString called name.

```
@property NSString *name;
```

2) In NibView.m create a function (e.g. helloWorld) and in that function do whatever you want to do with the passed in object.

```
- (void) helloWorld {
    NSLog(@"hello %@",self.name);
}
```

3) Write that method is NibView.h too

```
@property NSString *name;

- (void) helloWorld;
```

4) In the Class where you are passing data from (could be a ViewController for example), import your View Class

```
#import "NibView.h"
```

And write this code:

```
NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MyNibView" owner:self options:nil];
// At this point - (void)awakeFromNib is called
NibView *view = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
view.name = @"Bob";
// Now lets call the method "helloWorld"
[view helloWorld];
// This line sets the MyNibView as the UIView of a ViewController (only relevant for this example).
self.view = view;
```

Hope this helps others like it helped me